# Trying to Add Markers to Leaflet Map with button click (Using Angular)

Tags: json, angular, leaflet, mapping

I have the following code where I am creating a leaflet map on initial load of the page. I have about four jsons with lat/lon data that I would like to populate the map. What I'm looking for is four buttons that when clicked will add the json data as markers to the map.

What I'm getting is an error indicating the following:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addLayer').

Map Component:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MapPointsService } from './map-points.service';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css'],
})
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private map: L.Map | L.LayerGroup<any> | undefined;
  area: any;
  markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();

  private initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [4.5709, -74.2973],
      zoom: 3,
    });

    this.area = this.map;

    const tiles = L.tileLayer(
      'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 3,
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
      }
    );

    tiles.addTo(this.map);
  }

  constructor(private mapService: MapPointsService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
    // this.mapService.jsonMarkers(this.area);
  }

  addMarkers(): void {
    this.mapService.jsonMarkers(this.area);
  }
}
```

MapService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
// import { MapComponent } from './map.component';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MapPointsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  jsonMarkers(map: L.Map): void {
    this.http
      .get('/assets/data/<my_json>.json')
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        for (const area of res.<json_item>) {
          const lon = are.Longitude;
          const lat = are.Latitude;
          const marker = L.marker([lat, lon]);
          /*if (map.hasLayer(marker)) {
            map.removeLayer(marker);
          }*/
          marker.addTo(map);

          // console.log(markers);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Info Component that calls function

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MapPointsService } from '../map/map-points.service';
import { MapComponent } from '../map/map.component';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-information',
  templateUrl: './information.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./information.component.css'],
})
export class InformationComponent implements OnInit {
  /**
   * showSpinner boolean
   */
  showSpinner = false;
  constructor(
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private mapService: MapPointsService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  run(msg: string): void {
    const snackBarRef = this._snackBar.open('Running ' + msg, 'Close', {
      duration: 3000,
    });
    snackBarRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
      this.showSpinner = false;
    });
    this.showSpinner = true;
  }

  mapData() {
    let data = new MapComponent(this.mapService);
    data.addMarkers();
  }
}
```

Info Html

```
<button type="button" (click)='mapData()'></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you manually instantiate an Angular component with just the `new` keyword (`let data = new MapComponent(this.mapService)`), it will not be mounted anywhere, and in particular its lifecycle methods, like `ngAfterViewInit`, will not be called.

Then in your case, `this.map` and `this.area` remain `undefined`, leading to your error message.

Since you do not show your templates, it is hard to tell how your components are supposed to be related.

In case your `<app-information>` (`InformationComponent`) *contains* the `<app-map>` (`MapComponent`), you can use `@ViewChild` in `InformationComponent` to get a reference to the child `MapComponent`, and from there you can call its `addMarkers` method.

In case they are in the opposite situation, IIRC you can just request a `MapComponent` type in `InformationComponent` constructor, and Angular will inject it from its ancestors tree.

And if they are somehow siblings, then you could manage from a common ancestor:

- get a ref to the `MapComponent` as described first
- add an `@Output` event emitter on `InformationComponent` that fires when your button is clicked, and in the ancestor you listen to that event, and call the `MapComponent.addMarkers` method.